# Threadsafe buffer wrapping Stream

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, buffer

I'm using a `SslStream` on top of a `TcpClient`. Unfortunately the `SslStream`` does not support writing or reading from multiple threads at the same time. That's why I've wrote my own wrapper around it:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<byte> sendQueue;

private volatile bool oSending;

private readonly object writeLock;


public async void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
  if (oSending)
  {
    lock (writeLock)
    {
      foreach (var b in buffer)
      {
        sendQueue.Enqueue(b);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    oSending = true;
    await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count);
    oSending = false;

    lock (writeLock)
    {
      if (sendQueue.Count > 0)
      {
        Write(sendQueue.ToArray(), 0, sendQueue.Count);
        sendQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte>();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The intention behind that is the following:

1. If the stream is free, write immediately to the stream.
2. If the stream is busy, write to the buffer.
3. If the stream returns from sending, check if there is data in the queue and send it recursively.

I've tried several solutions so far, but it seems that everytime too much data is being sent.

P.S.: I know filling the queue bytewise is not nice, but that was just made quick and dirty.

Update: I've added the deletion of the queue according to Dirk's comment.

Comment: Do you ever remove items from the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Using [TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

public class DataflowStreamWriter
{
    private readonly MemoryStream _stream = new MemoryStream();
    private readonly ActionBlock<byte[]> _block;

    public DataflowStreamWriter()
    {
        _block = new ActionBlock<byte[]>(
                        bytes => _stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
    }

    public void Write(byte[] data)
    {
        _block.Post(data);
    }
}
```

---

Here's a better producer-consumer approach.

Whenever someone writes data to your `ConcurrentStreamWriter` instance, that data will be added to the buffer. This method is thread-safe and several threads may be writing data at once. These are your *producers*.

Then, you have one single *consumer* - consuming the data off the buffer and writing it to the stream.

A `BlockingCollection<T>` is used to communicate between the producers and the consumer. This way, the consumer sits idle if no one is producing. Whenever a producer kicks in and writes something to the buffer, the consumer will wake up.

The consumer is lazily initialized - it will be created when and only when some data is first available.

```
public class ConcurrentStreamWriter : IDisposable
{
    private readonly MemoryStream _stream = new MemoryStream();
    private readonly BlockingCollection<byte> _buffer = new BlockingCollection<byte>(new ConcurrentQueue<byte>());

    private readonly object _writeBufferLock = new object();
    private Task _flusher;
    private volatile bool _disposed;

    private void FlushBuffer()
    {
        //keep writing to the stream, and block when the buffer is empty
        while (!_disposed)
            _stream.WriteByte(_buffer.Take());

        //when this instance has been disposed, flush any residue left in the ConcurrentStreamWriter and exit
        byte b;
        while (_buffer.TryTake(out b))
            _stream.WriteByte(b);
    }

    public void Write(byte[] data)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("ConcurrentStreamWriter");

        lock (_writeBufferLock)
            foreach (var b in data)
                _buffer.Add(b);

        InitFlusher();
    }

    public void InitFlusher()
    {
        //safely create a new flusher task if one hasn't been created yet
        if (_flusher == null)
        {
            Task newFlusher = new Task(FlushBuffer);
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _flusher, newFlusher, null) == null)
                newFlusher.Start();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposed = true;
        if (_flusher != null)
            _flusher.Wait();

        _buffer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! The solution based on TPL Dataflow works great. Wouldn't it be even better to put it this way: _block = new ActionBlock<byte[]>(async bytes => await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)); I want to avoid blocking a thread for every single open connection I have.

Comment: @sqeez3r yes it would :)

Answer (score 1):

1. you're locking the access to a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` - you don't need that, the queue is thread-safe already
2. `if(oSending) {} else {oSending = true}` is not thread-safe. Two threads might read `oSending` as false, enter the else block, and set it to true. Now you have two threads writing to the stream.
3. As Dirk pointed out, you're not removing items from the queue.

---

My modifications:

1. Instead of using a boolean flag, use [`Monitor.TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead to try to access the stream. If the stream is currently being written to, the call will return immediately - and proceed to write to the buffer instead.
2. Implement `IDisposable` and make sure `Dispose` flushes the buffer.
3. Lock the queue only when writing to it, to maintain byte order
4. Changed signature to `async Task` from `async void`.

```
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte> _bufferQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte>();

private readonly object _bufferLock = new object();
private readonly object _streamLock = new object();
private readonly MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

public async Task Write(byte[] data, int offset, int count)
{
    bool streamLockTaken = false;

    try
    {
        //attempt to acquire the lock - if lock is currently taken, return immediately
        Monitor.TryEnter(_streamLock, ref streamLockTaken);

        if (streamLockTaken) //write to stream
        {
            //write data to stream and flush the buffer
            await stream.WriteAsync(data, offset, count);
            await FlushBuffer();

        }
        else //write to buffer
        {
            lock (_bufferLock)
                foreach (var b in data)
                    _bufferQueue.Enqueue(b);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (streamLockTaken)
            Monitor.Exit(_streamLock);
    }
}

private async Task FlushBuffer()
{
    List<byte> bufferedData = new List<byte>();
    byte b;
    while (_bufferQueue.TryDequeue(out b))
        bufferedData.Add(b);

    await stream.WriteAsync(bufferedData.ToArray(), 0, bufferedData.Count);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    lock(_streamLock)
        FlushBuffer().Wait();
}
```

Comment: 1. I'm using the lock because I don't want to lose the order of the bytes. I could remove this as soon as I'm adding the whole range of bytes at once. 2. How can I correct that? 3. I've forgotten to keep this when I was changing from one possible solution to another. (I started with `BeginWrite` and a Callback method.

Comment: @sqeez3r I've updated my post with an example - try it out. Regarding the lock, fair enough, but you only need the lock to write to the queue, not to read from it.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post and Thanks for the example. I've tried it but I'm running into a SynchronizationLockException. I'm currently trying to understand why this is happening.

Comment: @sqeez3r on which line does the exception occur?

Comment: @sqeez3r Oh damn, I just noticed you have a recursive call there! Hold on, give me a few minutes.

Comment: The exception occurs on Monitor.Exit(streamLock). The message is something like the object synchronization method was called by a non synchronized code block.

Comment: @sqeez3r Updated again - that code is working fine now, I've tested it myself. Instead of making a recursive call, when you acquire the stream lock, you write both the input data and the buffered data to the stream.

Comment: I also changed the name of some variables, to distinguish between the input data and the buffered data. The names were kind of ambiguous. And change the signature from `async void` to `async Task`.

Comment: @sqeez3r You should also implement a `Flush` method that is called on `Dispose` (and by the way, your "wrapper" class should implement `IDisposable`). This `Flush` method actually lock on the `streamLock` and flush whatever is in the buffer to the stream, to make sure no bytes are left behind.

Comment: This does not work for me. I've added some logs and hat happens is: 1. Writing to stream 2. Finished Writing to stream 3. Writing to queu. Could it happen that a second call enter the method just when the first call is finished with the Flush method? This would cause the second bytes, which will be written to the queue, to never being sent.

Comment: @sqeez3r That's the intent of the code.. if you acquire access to the stream, you write the input data *and* whatever's in the buffer to the stream. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: The problem which I see is that it could happen that a second call will write only to the queue but the data in the queue will never be written to the stream. In the beginning my communication is synchronous and then the problem occurs.

Comment: @sqeez3r That's true, that's why I added the flush method - to make sure any residue is flushed to the stream. Your initial strategy wouldn't run into this, but it's a much worse approach. If the stream is busy, you write to the queue buffer and make a recursive call - this is BAD. 1) you're "spinning" waiting for I/O to complete, 2) you're keeping all your threads busy making recursive calls, 3) it's possible to run into a StackOverflowException.

Comment: @sqeez3r You should either go with a full-fledged lock or with a producer-consumer design. I'll try to cook something up and get back to you soon ;)

Comment: @sqeez3r I added another answer with a producer-consumer approach. I tested it and it works fine, let me know if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just lock the underlying stream? I believe it can be as simple as this:

```
private readonly object writeLock = new Object();

public async void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
   lock (writeLock)
   {
      await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count);
   }
}
```

Also, with your queueing implementation, i think there is a change that a write can be queued bot never written to the stream. For instance, queueing after another thread has dequeued but before that thread has released its lock.

Comment: Simply locking the stream would result in many threads waiting for the lock. The application will handle up to 3000 connections and I cannort afford to run into too many locks.

Comment: @sqeez3r In that case, dcastro's code looks good. Keep in mind that even though most of the threads will release (buffer)locks fast, there will be threads that end up taking the toll of sending all data queued up from the other threads.